# Android multithreading in HostApduService (NFC)

Tags: android, multithreading, nfc, smartcard-reader, hce

I use the `processCommandApdu()` method in a subclass of [`HostApduService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/cardemulation/HostApduService.html#sendResponseApdu(byte[])) to react on NFC commands. This method gets called on the Android main thread. These commands should be processed and sent over the NFC channel sequentially. Therefore, I want to process them synchronously.

Is there any good way to enforce sequential order without blocking inside of the `processCommandApdu()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for you to synchronize command processing. Sequencing is inherent to the ISO/IEC 14443 protocol: A command exchange always consists of a command sent by the reader to the card (HCE device) and a response sent by the card (HCE) device to the reader. A reader won't issue a new command before the response to the previous command was received. If a command times out before a response is received by the reader, the reader will interpret this as if the connection to the card was lost.

Therefore, unless the reader resets/drops the connection, you won't receive a new command before you sent a response to the previous command (either through returning no-null from `processCommandApdu()`) or by calling `sendResponseApdu()`).